# msgpack: Unpack custom class without knowing the type

Tags: c++, msgpack

This is my code snippet to pack and unpack a known class:

```
MessageCoffeeIsReady input(1, "Black coffee is ready");

// ---- Serialize to buffer
msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
msgpack::pack(sbuf, input);

// ---- Send over line...

// ---- Unpack received buffer
msgpack::object_handle oh = msgpack::unpack(sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());
msgpack::object        obj = oh.get();

// ---- Convert to message
MessageCoffeIsReady result; // <- How do i know the msgpack::object contains `MessageCoffeIsReady`?
obj.convert(result);
```

My class looks like this:

```
class MessageCoffeeIsReady : public MessageBase
{
    protected:

        std::string m_name;
        int         m_id;

    public:

        MessageCoffeeIsReady(int id, std::string name)
        { m_id = id; m_name = name; }

        MSGPACK_DEFINE (m_name, m_id);
};
```

My question is: How do i know i have a received a message of type `MessageCoffeIsReady`?

Is there any internal typeid which i could use to convert to the specific class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsgPack is a JSON-like format without support for user-defined types in its protocol. When you use the `MSGPACK_DEFINE` macro, it just maps

But, you can still add your own type tag to support something like a discriminated union. That wouldn't let you identify any arbitrary object, but if you only plan to send one of a few types of objects, it's a good fit.

```
struct Any {
    std::string type;
    msgpack::object data;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(type, data);
};
```

This stored an object, and a string (type) to identify that object. Then you can pack objects into it:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b);
};

struct Bar {
    double c;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(c);
};

/* ... */

auto foo = Any { "foo", msgpack::object(Foo { 42, "hi" }, z) };
auto foo_obj = msgpack::object(foo, z);
auto bar = Any { "bar", msgpack::object(Bar { 25.5 }, z) };
auto bar_obj = msgpack::object(bar, z);
```

And to get things out, convert first to an any. Then convert to different types based on the tag:

```cpp
Any any;
obj.convert(any);
if (any.type == "foo") {
    Foo foo;
    any.data.convert(foo);
    std::cout << "foo(a=" << foo.a << ", b=" << foo.b << ")\n";
} else if (any.type == "bar") {
    Bar bar;
    any.data.convert(bar);
    std::cout << "bar(c=" << bar.c << ")\n";
}
```

Of course, that's only if you have some control over what objects you're seeing. If you really want to get granular, you can inspect the underlying JSON-like data manually. Here's a sample from the docs:

```cpp
if (o.type != msgpack::type::ARRAY) throw msgpack::type_error();
if (o.via.array.size != 2) throw msgpack::type_error();
v = my_class(
    o.via.array.ptr[0].as<std::string>(),
    o.via.array.ptr[1].as<int>());
```

Then it would be up to you to validate if the object you're inspecting is valid.

Comment: Do i need "z" (zone)? I get the following warning: "undefined reference to `msgpack::v1::adaptor::object<Foo, void>::operator()(msgpack::v2::object&, Foo const&) const'". Thank you.

Comment: I believe so. `z` in the example is a msgpack::zone, which allocates and owns memory for the objects. Just stick `msgpack::zone z;` at the top of the scope and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks, it works! @parktomatomi, great and flexible solution, thank you!

Comment: You can do similar thing using (std or boost) variant. Here is a boost variant example. https://wandbox.org/permlink/abciRlOK3T1EhpJs Note: `boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(e)>().pretty_name()` is implementation defined.